# How to use risc-v timer for accurate timing generation

Tags: assembly, timer, riscv

This question is regarding the machine timer of risc-v.
I'd like to use the timer to generate an accurate frequency interrupt.
My timer clock runs at 50MHz and I'd like to get an interrupt every 1ms.

I therefore set the `mtimecmp = 50000;`. As soon as `mtime >= mtimecmp` there's going to be an interrupt, according to the risc-v specification.

In my interrupt handler I do this:
`mtime -= 50000;`

This should prime the timer for the next interrupt at precisely 1kHz. The problem I'm facing is that the execution of above statement does require more than 0 clocks, which means the mtime register is set to a value a little bit too low, leading to an average interrupt frequency of slightly less than 1kHz.
I'm wondering if there's a solution to this. Is it possible to get an accurate interrupt frequency using the stock risc-v mtimer? How?

Comment: Can you do `mtimecmp += 50000;` instead?

Comment: According to the risc-v spec, the interrupt gets set if mtime >= mtimecmp. Incrementing mtimecmp doesn't work because of wrap around.

Comment: What wrap around?  These counters are 64 bits wide, so you have thousands of years to figure out the wrap around...

Comment: Ahhhh. Yes. Very good. I didn't think of that. With counters this big it will never wrap around. Thank you. If you want to write this as a solution I will gladly accept. Great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest trying `mtimecmp += 50000;` instead, and leave `mtime` alone.  (You can touch `mtimecmp`, I believe, to reset `MTIP`, so no need to touch `mtime`.)

Even on 32-bit machines, these counters are 64 bits wide, so wrap around will take thousands of years.

(The privileged spec also provides a sequence for updating `mtimecmp` on a 32-bit machine such that an intermediate value when written using multiple 32-bit writes does not generate an erroneous interrupt.)